# Matrix and Solspace Importer issue with saving properly

Tags: matrix, solspace, pixelandtonic, solspace-importer

I'm not sure which plugin is at fault here, but here goes. Using the latest version of all plugins, and EE.

I have an Importer task to create entries, from a feed of about 20. One field in this feed is an of images and alt text. This is mapped correctly to a Matrix field, and seemingly importing fine for all entries. See below.

[image]

However, for some entries, when attempting to output in templates, these rows in the Matrix field aren't being displayed.

```
{if '{images:total_rows}'}
    {images}
        {image_src}
    {/images}
{if:else}
    no img
{/if}
```

What's more, using the above code, you'd expect even if there was a problem with mapping, that `{images:total_rows}` would return false, and print `no img`. This isn't the case, and the whole code is seemingly skipped over.

What makes me think this is an issue with Importer, is if I go to the offending entry, where I can see the rows in the Matrix as above, and re-save that entry (without changing anything) the templating works as expected. Is it somehow possible Importer isn't saving the Matrix field properly after importing?

Answer (score 1):

I would query the matrix table for an entry that doesn't work and one that does and compare the 2 to see if there is any difference.

Comment: I would also look at differences at the database level, looking at `exp_matrix_data` and the corresponding column for the Matrix field in `exp_channel_data`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your Matrix data in your entry, that means the data is stored somewhere on your database (or else the Matrix field would be empty). Have you tried using `{if images:total_rows > 0}` instead of a true/false condition (i.e. `{if '{images:total_rows}'}`)? Matrix data is likely stored in exp_matrix_XXX tables (where Matrix data gets stored) but not in exp_channel_data (where *searchable* Matrix data gets stored), which `{if '{images:total_rows}'}` might be relying on.